# are there anybody can help me ? i'm writting a program ( reversing an array ), but it doesn't run :(

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk, c#-2.0

I'm writing a program about reversing an array with 3 methods (GenerateNumber, reverse and PrintOut).

Unfortunately it doesn't run. Can you help me to find the error and fix them?

Why doesn't it run?

```
  public class Program
{
    static int[] GenerateNumber()
    {
        string a = Console.ReadLine();
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
        int[] number = new int [b];
        string[] c = new string[b];
        for (int index = 0; index < number.Length; index++)
        {
            c[index] = Console.ReadLine();
            number [index]= Convert.ToInt32(c[index]);
       }
        return number;
    }
    static int[] reverse(int[] array)
    {

        for (int index =0; index <array.Length; index++)
        {
            int c = array[index];
            array[index] = array[array.Length - index - 1];
            array[array.Length - index - 1]= c;
        }
        return array;
    }
    static int[] PrintOut (int[] array)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index > array.Length; index++)
            Console.Write(array[index]);
        return array;
    }
           static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] number = GenerateNumber();
        reverse(number);
        PrintOut(number);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Did not read through fully, but it looks like ` index <array.Length` should be ` index <array.Length/2`.

Comment: `for (int index = 0; index > array.Length; index++)` should be `index < array.Length`

Comment: oh, i see it, thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate cause of the misbehaviour is in the

```
static int[] PrintOut (int[] array)
{
    for (int index = 0; index > array.Length; index++) // <- wrong condition
        Console.Write(array[index]);
```

The comparison should be `<` instead of `>`:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
```

A better choice, however, is `foreach` loop instead of `for`

```
    foreach (var item in array)
      Console.Write(item); // propably, you want WriteLine not Write
```

Some suggestions:

```
  public class Program {
    static int[] GenerateNumber() {
      // You don't want "c" array, but "number"
      int[] number = new int [Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];

      for (int index = 0; index < number.Length; index++)  
        number [index] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

      return number;
    }

    // Nice implementation, nothing to improve but naming (reverse -> Reverse)  
    static int[] Reverse(int[] array) {
        for (int index = 0; index <array.Length; index++) {
            int c = array[index];
            array[index] = array[array.Length - index - 1];
            array[array.Length - index - 1] = c;
        }
        return array;
    }

    static int[] PrintOut (int[] array) {
        // foreach is easier to implement and easier to read
        foreach (var item in array)
          Console.WriteLine(item); // <- you, probably, want WriteLine not Write 

        return array;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] number = GenerateNumber();
        Reverse(number);
        PrintOut(number);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: thanks :D. now i'm really understand the uses of foreach :D

Comment: @Vũ Đức Dũng: you're welcome! Laziness and readability (it's .net, not you and me who should compute indexes and the like things) are powerful means :)

Comment: in the GenerateNumber Method of this program, i try to use foreach method.



 
** foreach (var item in number)
 Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 return number;
** [code] ( this is the frist time i used this web, so i don't how to write a code :D )
But the program doesn't run. can you explain it for me pls ?

Comment: @Vũ Đức Dũng: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` *returns* an integer value whcih you have to *assign*. Be careful, please, `foreach` is not a magic wand, this loop type has its own res: you can't *modify* the array, and you can't obtain the *item's index*. In your code, `for` is better approach then `foreach`... (you have to modify - i.e. assign the user input - and you want to know item's index)